# why distinct and order by doesn't work together in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, distinct

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhSDk.png) I am learning how to order by is used in SQL query, then I learned that order by and distinctly don't work together but, when I try to do it practically it worked. I am so confused even after asking chatgpt what the relationship is between order by and distinct.

I learned that when executing SQL queries, the ORDER BY clause comes after the SELECT clause. This means that the database will first retrieve the data specified in the SELECT clause, and then sort it based on the criteria specified in the ORDER BY clause. If the column used in the ORDER BY clause is not present in the SELECT clause, the database will automatically include that column in the select and do order by on both the columns and give result column only column given in SELECT.

However, when using both DISTINCT and ORDER BY together, the outcome may not be what is expected. This is because DISTINCT acts on both the columns in the SELECT clause and the column in the ORDER BY clause. This may cause unexpected results, especially in MySQL.

I found that when I tried this in practice, it still produced the desired results, which makes me question if I learned something incorrectly or if there is missing information that I am unaware of.

I am using the MYSQL database.

Comment: What database are you using? For example, in PostgreSQL the manual explains how distinct and order by interact.

Comment: When you do `SELECT DISTINCT`, only SELECT list items can be used in the ORDER BY. Which makes full sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some spaces before your unique value. It will be appropriate to perform TRIM/RTRIM and remove these spaces in the DISTINC clause itself.

It should be something like this:

```
DISTINCT TRIM(value) AS trim_value
...
ORDER BY trim_value
```

Also, it is possible that these are not spaces but some other characters which need to be replace, too.